# Breadcrumbs for some content types

Tags: 7, nodes, breadcrumbs

I'm using breadcrumbs generally throughout my Drupal 7 site and all working well.

However, for news articles, I don't want to have to add each into the menu structure as over time, this will be a little out of control.

I'd like content of the type = news to have

Home > News > Title

with an active link back to my /news page.

Is this possible whilst still using the normal breadcrumb for other content?

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, and what's in your main menu, https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_menu_breadcrumbs might be an option

Comment: Thanks Clive. That looks good but sadly, I'm on a D7 site! Should have made that clear.

Comment: Oh then good news - [Crumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) has you covered! Great module

Comment: Thanks again Clive. It didn't seem to quite get me there, but this blog helped: https://www.webwash.net/control-breadcrumbs-using-path-breadcrumbs-in-drupal-7/ I used Path Breadcrumbs to define per node, but turned off the global setting so my menu breadcrumbs were retained.

Comment: Besides Crumbs (my answer below), there is also [Menu position](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position), which I think also affects the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, if you want to do this with [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs):

Go to /admin/structure/crumbs/entity-parent.
For content type "News", enter "news" as parent path.

Likely it already works now.
If not, check the order and status of plugins on /admin/structure/crumbs.
Also check /admin/structure/crumbs/debug, where you can simulate breadcrumb-building for specific pages.

Comment: Does Drupal have ANY breadcrumb managing tool/options in the default core-recommended distribution?

Comment: @mevsme This specific question was for Drupal 7 (tagged "7"). You gotta look for another question.